# Использование open-vm-tools для получения свойств VM машины

Tags: linux, vmware

Имеется собранный [open-vm-tools](https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools). Машинка виртуальная стартует, но тулза не запускается. При попытке чекнуть тулзу скриптом `/usr/local/bin/vmware-checkvm` получаю ошибку:

> /usr/local/bin/vmware-checkvm: error while loading shared libraries: libvmtools.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Самое интересное что скрипт для запуска демона ищет данный бинарник по такому адрессу: `/usr/bin/vmware-checkvm`

В чем может быть проблема такая? При билде данной тулы я мог что то не указать? Сделал все по описанию. 
Заранее всех благодарю за информацию.

Comment: а какой версии vCenter и update?

Comment: попробуйте в env прописать `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/bin/` и попробуйте еще раз. что выдает?

Comment: Как оказалось проблема в том что для данного исошника что я пытался это сделать в заготовках уже давно лежал данный скрипт) он просто с давних времен там остался. И получалось что пакет мой ставился а потмо этот скрипт затирался) смешно...

Comment: Вообще, я сейчас нашел в репах уже готовый деп пакет. При попытке проверить стутус vmtoolsd плучаю ошибку "vmtoolsd is not running ... failed!" . посмотрел через ldd зависимости, все в норме. в системе все присутствует. Может кто подскажет как в данной ситуации докапаться до истины?)